# EditText - What is the difference between inputType="" and inputType="text"?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

What is the difference between inputType="text" and not having the inputType field at all in an XML layout? The behavior does not appear to be different when I remove inputType completely (likely because I am just constantly updating uneditable text), but I'd just like to make sure.

This is in response to a strange ICS bug where if you have an EditText with any kind of inputType="__", a spellcheck is done and a red underline is placed on the misspelled word.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some difference interms of input richness.  Here is a link [Why Input type?](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) and [Inputtype interface API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NULL)

In Inputtype interface link if you observe **TYPE_CLASS_TEXT** and **TYPE_NULL** you will clearly understand the difference.

Comment: Okay I made a typo, I'm actually dealing with a TextView, not an EditText. This textview constantly gets updated with strings, and is not (and should not) be editable by users. Should input richness still be considered? And by richness, it seems that you mean plain text vs rich text format?

Comment: I don't think it applies for TextView.